# Print data on Zebra printer from browser (Windows or MacOS)

Tags: javascript, browser, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I have developed a web application that needs to print on Zebra (GT800) silently directly from browser. The web application is hosted by Amazon AWS, so it is in a different network (so I can't open a socket via PHP directly from the server).
I need to find the best way to print from client browser (such as Firefox or Chrome) to Windows or MacOS on Zebra printer via raw commands ZPL or EPL.

I tried this project https://github.com/qzind/qz-print but it not seems to be the best solution because each print job needs to confirm and besides I need to purchase a certificate. Is there a more simple and clean solution through JS, jQuery or third-party plugins in Chrome or Firefox?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you do not wish to purchase a certificate, QZ Tray now offers the option to provide your own certificate https://qz.io/wiki/signing-messages#advanced

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to install webserver with php in the client? Then you can pass the data from the server to the client via POST, then let the local webserver handle the printing job.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Zebra's application for this, Zebra Browser Print, only limit is to have printer connected to USB or Network